# Unmount a component

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

in my code I have a problem with Unmount a component. In particular when i click on "notify" I get some values, and when I click on unsubscribe it should unmount what the notify has save. 
But I get this kind of error: "**Undefined is not an Object (Evaluating "p.default.unregisterNotification (o.notifyHandle).catch")**"

I use the command .remove() but it doesn't work.

**page1**

```
if (property.indexOf('Notify') === 0 || property.indexOf('Indicate') === 0) {
            if (!this.notifyHandle) {
                BleHelper.registerNotification(peripheral.id, serviceUuid, char.characteristic, this._onCharValueUpdate)
                    .then(handle => {
                        this.notifyHandle = handle;
                        this.forceUpdate();
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.warn(err)
                        ErrorRegistry.putError('GATT Register Notification', err);
                    });
            } else {
                BleHelper.unregisterNotification(this.notifyHandle)
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.warn(err)
                        ErrorRegistry.putError('GATT Unregister Notification', err);
                    })
                this.notifyHandle = null;
                this.forceUpdate();
            }
```

**page 2**

```
registerNotification(peripheralId, serviceId, charId, callback) {
        return new Promise(
            (resolve, reject) => {
                BleManager.startNotification(peripheralId, serviceId, charId)
                    .then(() => {
                        resolve(bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic', callback));
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.warn('BleHelper registerNotification', err);
                        reject(err)
                    })
            }
        )
    }

    unregisterNotification(handle) {
        handle.remove();
    }
```

**EDIT**

I have tried to do in this way:

```
unregisterNotification(handle) {
      return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
          BleManager.unregisterNotification(this.notifyHandle)
          .then(() => {
            resolve(handle.remove());
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.warn('Error', err);
            reject(err)
          })
          }
      )
    }
```

Now I don't get the error but i don't remove the value when i click on notify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BleHelper.unregisterNotification(this.notifyHandle)
  .catch(err => {
    console.warn(err)
    ErrorRegistry.putError('GATT Unregister Notification', err);
  })

// ...

  unregisterNotification(handle) {
    handle.remove();
  }
```

`unregisterNotification` isn't returning anything, so you can't call `.catch` on undefined. Either have unregisterNotification return a promise, or remove the `.catch`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i understand what you said but I don't understand your code, you have merge the code from the 2 pages? @NicholasTower

Comment: That code was just a repeat of your code, but with the problematic parts in closer proximity to highlight the issue. It does not fix the issue.

Comment: Yes, I understood later xD I update my code following your direction (maybe)